# Rendering comment form into other view except post view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to render my comment form into another view except the post view, but i am getting the error:
No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments", :post_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:post_id]

My models:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :comments
   mount_uploader :image, AvatarUploader
   validates :content, presence: true, length: {minimum: 5}
   delegate :username, :username=, :email, :email=,:avatar, :avatar=, :to => :user, allow_nil: true

end


class Wall < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post
  has_many :users
  has_many :comments

  delegate :username, :username=,:avatar, :avatar=, :email, :email=, :to => :user, allow_nil: true
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

And my form that i am rendering in the wallcontroller -> index.html.erb

```
<div class="comments">
<%= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'comments js-auto-size', id: 'alex2' ,:rows => 1  %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :uploads
  resources :users
  resources :walls
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
  root 'walls#index'
end
```

Adding this form to the post view works with no problem, however i wish to render both this form and comments into the wall index.html.erb

This app is basically like a facebook, so everything will be rendered on 1 page.

Comment: Could you show your routes.rb ?

Comment: Added the routes to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wall index shows all posts (presumably) so you must have some construct like...

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
...

<% end %>
```

So between the `do` and the `end` you have a `post` object, so you can render the form without the instance variable, instead as...

```
<div class="comments">
<%= form_for ([post, post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'comments js-auto-size', id: 'alex2' ,:rows => 1  %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow awesome its showing, cant believe it was something so small! i was stuck on this for 5 days now!!!